# Read timed out. error while sending a POST request to a node.js API

Tags: python, node.js

I have a node.js API as below to which I send a POST request from python as below,the issue am facing is if I remove the 
`headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}` the POST goes thorugh,if not i get a  `Read timed out. error`, can anyone provide guidance on how to fix this timeout error ?

**node.js endpoint**

```
app.post("/api/bats_push",(req, res) => {
        //console.log("Calling bats_push...")
        const d = {
            method: req.method,
            headers: req.headers,
            query: req.query,
            body: ''
        }

        req.on('data', (c) => {
            //console.log(c)
            d.body = d.body + c
        });

        req.on('end', () => {
            DATA.push(d);
            res.end('Saved BATS job details');
            //res.status(200).json({
              //message: "Saved BATS job details",
              //posts: req.body
          //}); 
        });
});
```

**Python POST**

```
try:
json"},timeout=10.0)
    r = requests.post(webhook_url,data=json_data.encode("utf8"),verify=False,headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})
    print "posted"
    print(r.status_code, r.reason)
    print r.url
    print r.text
except Exception as e:
    print (e)
```

Error:-

```
  InsecureRequestWarning)
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='company.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10.0)
```

Comment: Sounds like "application/json" is not an acceptable content type

Comment: @how to make it acceptable?

Comment: Have you tried content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8" ?

Comment: @JacobIRR - where exactly this need to be put? in the node.js API,do you minding being specific?

Comment: Are you using any body parsers?

Comment: The error is on localhost and the code is exactly the same as I posted

Comment: Can you show your express setup, all middlewares before `.post`.

Comment: is this issue fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems that you are using express.js. I believe that your problem is, that body is actually already parsed. You can check it by reading `req.body`. The situation is caused because express.js already read whole body (due to the content type) and trying to read body again will cause timeout (event `data` and event `end` are not emitted).
There are several ways how to fix it.

1. disable express.js body parser - or reconfigure it to ignore json
2. remove reading body code and use directly `req.body`

```
app.post("/api/bats_push",(req, res) => {
        //console.log("Calling bats_push...")
        const d = {
            method: req.method,
            headers: req.headers,
            query: req.query,
            body: req.body
        }

        DATA.push(d);
        res.end('Saved BATS job details');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

according to requests why not use this:

```
#replace this 
r = requests.post(webhook_url,data=json_data.encode("utf8"),verify=False,headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})

#by this...assuming that 'data' is a dict
r = requests.post(webhook, json=data, verify=False)
```

Comment: I need to get it working with `headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}`

Comment: I get the same error with `r = requests.post(webhook, json=data, verify=False)`

Comment: remove "verify=False" and try again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it could be something related to your SSL.
Check if you get the same error sending a request to your localhost with the server running.

Answer (score 0):

From your question,the key word is:

if I remove the  headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"} the POST goes thorugh.

The reason may clear:it is a wrong way use about the header.

Simpler say: the node.js app check the header before into the logic code.

if do not send the header by ourself,the requests part use the default headers below:

```
{
  'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.22.0', 
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 
  'Accept': '*/*', 
  'Connection': 'keep-alive', 
}
```

through the requests's code can print the default headers when post.

you just use the header

```
{"Content-Type": "application/json"}
```

may resulting in the node.js app think the reqeust not legitimate(the word I do not know how to explain in English).

If the node.js app is developed by yourself, you can try to find the frame's check after create a tcp connection and before the logic code,the way is to read the source code.

If the node.js app is not developed by yourself,try to change the header mixing the default header to find which header key checked by the node.js app.

But in my thought,It is import ,about the node.js app's  interface description:

we just use by interface description engouth,just need to know the error from the api  header's  check, which the description should show but not show to us?

Hope to help you.